# Different php exec() output from command line and from browser (Apache2)

Tags: php, exec, rsync

from command line:

```
sudo -u apache php -r 'exec("rsync -avi --rsh=\"ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -p22\" --omit-dir-times /var/www/html/ test@out:/var/www/html/ 2>&1", $a, $n);print_r($a);';
```

returns this (and I want such output):

```
 Array
(
    [0] => sending incremental file list
    [1] => <f+++++++++ testrsync
    [2] =>
    [3] => sent 9143 bytes  received 47 bytes  18380.00 bytes/sec
    [4] => total size is 25642011  speedup is 2790.21
)
```

but from Apache2:

```
exec("rsync -avi --rsh=\"ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -p22\" --omit-dir-times /var/www/html/ test@out:/var/www/html/ 2>&1", $a, $n);
print_r($a);
```

I get this output:

```
array (
  0 => 'sending incremental file list',
  1 => ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' '',
  312 => 'sent 139318 bytes  received 183398 bytes  215144.00 bytes/sec',
  313 => 'total size is 25642011  speedup is 79.46',
)
```

Before testing I delete **testrsync** file and both from terminal and from browser rsync successfully transfers **testrsync** file but in apache2 it does not show this line:

```
<f+++++++++ testrsync
```

I want to get list of modified files by Rsync in the browser.

Apache/2.2.15, PHP 5.4.20, Centos 6.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the problem:

Rsync output looks like this:

```
[1] => <f..t...... logo-1.png

[2] => <f..t...... logo.png
```

and browser parses < as new tag so I get empty output but source code shows full output. I spent more than a hour to debug it ;D

Answer (score 1):

You can save that file (use php headers) as **.txt instead of html or php**. No formation will be happened in browsers